# How do I reduce the time to write large CSV (12 Go) to GCS bucket with Pyspark? (>6h)

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Dataproc cluster to transform many CSV files stored in GCS, but when I write the CSV to a GCS bucket this takes too much time, 7h for one file (12 go).

This is the code that I used to read & write the CSV:

`df = spark.read.options(delimiter='¤',header="true").csv('gs://'+bucket_name+'/'+file_name)`

`df.write.format('csv').option("header","True").option('sep','¤').save('gs://'+bucket_name+'/'+target_obj_name+'_tmp'+'/'+filename)`

How can i optimise this operation?

Comment: What does 'Go' refer to as in '12 Go'?

Comment: what's your cluster definition? how many partitions your df have before writing? It's hard to investigate without knowing those basic information

Comment: @Chris: Possibly "[Gigaoctet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gigaoctet)", French for Gigabyte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read will be a single Spark task, but the transformation and write will be parallelised by Spark, so increasing the size of your cluster will increase the parallelism and correspondingly decrease the execution time.